# Place a background Image behind a grouped UITableView

Tags: image, uitableview, uiview, background, behind

I've a grouped UITableView which has been resized and rounded. I would like to place a view BEHIND this table.I've tried:

```
[self.tableView addSubview:backgroundView];
[self.tableView sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView];
```

but it didn't work. This is what I obtain:

[image: rounded uitableview]

I would like to have the background in place of the black space.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `[self.tableView setBackgroundView:backgroundView];`?

Comment: this place the image as background of the tableview (so limited in the area of the grouped table),instead I need a view BEHIND the table.

Comment: I'm not clear on the difference that you're describing.  Do you mean something like `[self.tableView.superview addSubview:backgroundView];  ...;`?

Comment: yes,I'm trying that as well but it's not working. Getting really crazy.

Comment: At this point, I have no idea what it would need to look like for you to call it 'working'.  :)

Comment: I've placed your code in viewWillAppear: and viewDidLoad
but nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

Bear with me I'm a beginner. I just ran into this problem and I found two solutions. In my case, I was using a UITableView object.

To begin, add the background image into your app's directory. I put mine in "Supporting Files"

You can add the image as a UIColor object:

```
    ...
    [resultsTable setBackGroundColor:setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]]];
    ...
```

The problem with this method is that it will repeat your background image because it's treating it as a pattern.

The better way:

```
     // Create a string to store the path location of your image, otherwise you would have    to provide an exact path name
     NSString *backPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background"
     ofType:@"jpg"];

    // Create a UIImage Object to store the image.
     UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:backPath];

     // Create a UIImageView which the TableView 
     UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bgImage];

     // Set your TableView's background property, it takes a UIView Obj.
     [resultsTable setBackgroundView: bgView];
     .....
```